# Is it possible for air capacitors to leak current?

Tags: capacitance, dielectric

Do air capacitors leak current (ie through the dielectric) and if so, how? For thunder, the air ionizes, i.e. the dielectric breaks down if the electric field strength is enough, which allows it to conduct. Is the principle same?

Assume there's no physical damage or whatsoever.

For other dielectrics I suppose it's not 100% perfect insulating materials so it might happen that very tiny current passes through, and after some time (although, for a high quality dielectric this will be very long) it gets discharged.

Comment: Your intuition is correct - current leakage occurs via sparking from one plate to the other. In more easily ionizable dielectrics, this phenomenon is much less violent.

Comment: It the voltage is high enough any dielectric can approach its breakdown point and leak. The only time I can ever recall seeing air capacitors, though, is as variable capacitors for old RF tuning circuits, and I'm pretty sure that for that application the voltages are small enough that leakage is nil.

Comment: @SamuelWeir It is when transmitting that in the antenna tuning unit containing an air capacitor the voltages can be large. Thus the spacing of the plates becomes an important factor.

Comment: @Farcher - Yeah, I guess that for an RF tuning circuit in a transmitter the voltages can probably get pretty high. The only time I've personally seen air capacitors is in old TVs and radios as variable air capacitors in their receiving circuits.

Answer (score 1):

An air capacitor should have some leakage current (impulses, if the voltage is not too high for  enabling permanent ionization), since air contains tiny amounts of radioactive gas like CO2 (C14) or Radon and a capacitor is not always perfectly shielded from radiation/particles generated by processes high above the earth or from the natural or man-made radioactivity. The ionization current depends on many parameters like gap width, temperature, pressure, recombination,voltage, free travel distance, kind of molecule/atom etc. So an air capacitor can work like a (insensitive and unintended) detector for ionization processes.